# Clear left/right of img in a stylesheet

Tags: css, image, stylesheet

I am wondering on how I can make images within a div with clear left/right?

PHP has pictures and texts, and the pictures has to have a clear left/right to make it look good. No, I can't do that in the PHP-file, already asked my teacher :)

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="four columns" id="weather">
    <h2>Text</h2>
   <?php include 'yr.php'; ?>
</div>
```

The #weather.four.columns is correct, and I thought I could solve the problem with img#weather.four.columns, but no.

```
#weather.four.columns {
    border-left:none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border-right:1px solid #c4effe;
}

img#weather.four.columns {
    clear:both;

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be `#weather img{clear:both;}`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#weather img
{
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Highlight code then press ctrl +k to indent it and highlight it as code

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
img#weather.four.columns {
    clear:both;
}
```

to

```
#weather img{ /*this line */
    clear:both;
}
```

What you've done is try to find an image with the id of `weather`. What you want is the `weather` id to find the `img` tag inside it. You just had it backwards :)